# How to interpret $(2n)!$

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

It's all in question: how to interpret the factorial from $2n$? Is $(2n)!$ equal to $n!\times  n!$ ?

The problem is in Combinations if the combinations is $\binom{2n}3$.

P.S.

The main problem is how to write $C^3_{2n}$ (C is for combinations in combinatiorics)

Comment: Is it true when $n=1$?

Comment: @John yes it is true

Comment: @eLbor. I think not. $(2\times1)!=2!=2$ but $1!=1$ and $1\times1=1\neq2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules of writing mathematics state that if you do not enclose the factor 2 in parentheses, then $2n!$ is interpreted as 
$$2n!=2\times(n!)=2\times1\times2\times3\times\cdots\times n.$$ 
The factorial of $2n$ has to be written as $(2n)!$. Using the definition of the factorial, we have

$$(2n)!=1\times2\times3\times\cdots\times(2n-1)\times(2n).$$

So to answer your question, the factorial of $2n$ that enters in the expression
$\binom{2n}3$ is not equal to $n!\times n!$ (which is written $n!^2$)... it is a larger number (can you see why ?).

Note: The combination (or binomial coefficient) $\binom{2n}{3}$ is equal to 
$$ \binom{2n}3=\frac{(2n)\times(2n-1)\times(2n-2)}{1\times2\times3}.$$

Comment: yes but the main problem is how to write $C^3_{2n}$ (C is for combinations in combinatiorics,)

Comment: \C^3_{2n} <- put $$ around this

Comment: @eLbor. The notation $\binom{2n}{3}$ is equivalent (and should be used instead of) the notation $\mathrm C^3_{2n}$.

Answer (score 1):

$(2n)! = 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\cdots\cdot (2n-1)\cdot 2n$, as usual.

Comment: ... and this is in general much larger than $n!\cdot n!$. In fact the quotient $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$ is a binomial coefficient $2n\choose n$.

Comment: Ok but You are saying that there is no way to convert to something I can use in division

Comment: @eLbor No, noone is saying that, this answer gives you a form that can be used in division. You would probably get better answers if you tell us what you actually want to do with $(2n)!$.

Answer (score 1):

Interpret it as

$$1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-1)\cdot n\cdot(n+1)\cdot\ldots(2n-1)\cdot2n.$$

Verify that this is different from $n!\cdot n!=(n!)^2$ instead.